# Write the text from input field to value onkeyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible with jquery, or javascript to write the text which I enter to a text are to the value of the input?

Comment: Yes it is possible to write the text you have entered in your text area to an input field. However you may lose the line breaks.

Comment: Are you looking for the "how to" or just "is it possible"?

Comment: I'm looking for the howto :)

Comment: So [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: well, i don't know how to get the text, but how to write it:

document.getElementBytagName("fieldname").value="TEXT";

Answer (score 1):

Not too sure what you're trying to do, but maybe this will help:

```
$('.textarea').keyup(function() {
   $('.another_input').val(this.value);
});
```